# Puppeteer - Search for element by div class - Return all div classes for Element

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

I have a site I need to scrape, to find a list of classes on a div, by searching for a particular div class.

For instance, if we have the code:

```
//HTML on site
<div class="main">Main Stuff</div>
<div class="class1 class 2 specialclass">Other Stuff</div>
<div class="footer">Footer Stuff</div>'
```

I need to search for "special class" as a div class, and return the list of classes for that div, so I would want to return:
`class1 class2 specialclass`

I'm using a Wikibooks site as an example and running this code:

```
//Puppeteer Code
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const devices = require('puppeteer/DeviceDescriptors');

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.wikibooks.org/');

const myclassname = await page.evaluate(() => 
document.querySelector('.lang1').innerText);

console.log(myclassname);
```

It searches for the div with a class of `lang1`, the default language div near the top of the screen, and returns me the text of the object, but I don't know what to change `innerText` to in order to get the class names of the object, so it will return `central-featured-lang lang1`, all of the classes of that object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the following element from the [webpage you specified](https://www.wikibooks.org/):

```
<div class="central-featured-lang lang1" lang="en">...</div>
```

You can use [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) or [`getAttribute('class')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to obtain the content of the [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) attribute of an element:

```
const myclassname = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.lang1' ).className);

console.log(myclassname); // Returns "central-featured-lang lang1"
```

Or, you can return an iterable array of the classes of an element using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```
const myclassnamearray = await page.evaluate(() => [...document.querySelector('.lang1').classList]);

console.log(myclassnamearray[0]); // Returns "central-featured-lang"
console.log(myclassnamearray[1]); // Returns "lang1"
```

Comment: You not only answered my original question, but gave me an additional piece of functionality that I actually need in my project! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

use

```
.getAttribute("class");
```

for example

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].getAttribute("class");
```